# Passing a generic parameter into a function which has a specific inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I have this function doing queries based on a `customerId` and `entityModel`. I want to make it generic for all different models. In other words, I want to pass `CustomerFeatureEntity` class as a parameter into this function:

```
public TableQuery<CustomerFeatureEntity> StorageQuery(string customerId)
{
    TableQuery<CustomerFeatureEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerFeatureEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, customerId));
}
```

Also it would be nice if I make sure that parameter inheritance from `TableEntity` class. Is either one of those possible to be done in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd just need to redefine it to use generics with a where constraint.

```
public TableQuery<T> StorageQuery<T>(string customerId) where T : TableEntity
{
    TableQuery<T> query = new TableQuery<T>()
        .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", 
            QueryComparisons.Equal, customerId));
}
```

Comment: That was fast David. Thanks.